# I need to ScrollTo Image by float numbers in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

```
myimage.SrollTo(int x,int y);
```

I need to Scroll it By Float Numbers but the method is only for Int numbers
And I need Accurate numbers Like 3,4 - 3,5 - 3,6 If I Rounded Them They well be 3 and it well be the same and it isn't

Comment: You will get better answers if you described what you want to achieve through float numbers. The `scrollTo` method does not have a variant that takes floats.

Comment: I need To Scroll Image By ScrollTo
The Values are in Hertez For Tunning
Like Pano Tuner app

Comment: The `scrollTo(int x, int y)` represents pixels on the image. They **cannot** be floats. If you are scrolling to different parts of the image, you will have a fixed `int` difference between any two points.

Answer (score 0):

`Math.round()` will round your float to the closest int. And then you can add that as an argument

Comment: No, I need Accurate numbers Like 3,4 - 3,5 - 3,6 If I Rounded Them They well be 3 and it well be the same and it isn't